# Is Scala installed multiple times if using Scala IDE, Scala on the command line, and SBT?

Tags: eclipse, bash, scala

As far as I understand, I have multiple versions/installs of Scala to be able to access it via Eclipse, bash/OS-X shell, and for SBT:

- one version of Scala as supplied with the Scala IDE;
- the Scala binaries to be able to run it from within a shell; and,
- Scala as part of SBT.

Is my understanding correct? If so, is there any way to run with just the one version/install for all uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my understanding correct?

No. You don't "install" Scala. You just have multiple versions of `Executable Jar file` of `scala-compiler`, `scala-library` etc. The version that you have on your `PATH` is the one that seems installed but its nothing more than running a `jar` file.

TO run on a specific version, just add the `scala` jars to the classpath of your project. If you are using SBT, you can specify the scalaVersion in your build.sbt and it will add the proper Jar to the classpath

Comment: Thank you. It has taken a couple of days to get my head around this completely, but everything is now clear to me.